# tablespace thru dblinks

Tags: oracle

How can one create an tablespace using dblinks?
Is there any way how do we create a tablespace in this fashion?
what are the pre-requisities.

Answer (score 3):

You can not, you should not perform DDL over a database link. DDL does an implicit commit and a commit on the remote site is not allowed.

```
ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database
```

You can use the job queues - so that a transaction is performed on the remote system, eg:

```
dbms_job.submit@remote( l_job, 'execute immediate ''create table t ( x int )''' ); 
commit;
```

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:597877500346143250)

Comment: I believe you mean dbms_job.submit@remote not dbms_job@remote.submit.